# Open a Modal when updating location in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm working with React Router and I need to show a modal when the url locations change without refreshing the page. How can I do that approach ?

Answer (score 0):

create a route for same component with extra param and add modal id param is exist in that component

```
<Route path="/users">
            <Users />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/users/:x">
            <Users />
  </Route>
```

then

```
var {x} = useparam();

if(x)
//open modal
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the history API to subscribe to location changes. In the example below the `history.listen()` function returns an unsubscribing function so we can clean up after the component unmounts.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

const App = ({ history }) => {
    const history = useHistory();

    useEffect(() => history.listen(({action, location})) => {
        //modal logic
    }), []);

    //...
}

export default App;
```

Comment: But the modal will be open and the redirect will not have effect ?